# Latex and applicant tracking systems

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I have been using a PDF resume written in Latex, and it recently occurred to me that Applicant Tracking Systems used by human resources may not be parsing my resume correctly. According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/3nr2vn/how_can_i_ensure_that_my_latex_resume_is_readable/) Reddit post, I need to add

```
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

I also have

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{helvet} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

Is there anything that could be preventing my resume from being parsed correctly?

Comment: Thoughts, anyone?

Comment: I am in exactly the same place as you, my efforts so far have included submitting my resume to some automated parsers. I get some strange results, but I haven't quite gotten as far in to the fix-it-with-better-coding avenue as you.

Comment: @repurposer What automated parsers have you used? Like ones that gave strange results.

Comment: rezscore and topresume. Not sure how private the info is, mind

Comment: @repurposer just make a resume with Lorem ipsum. Same difference really

Comment: @user369210 the `glyphtounicode` invocations are not required when using a `otf` font with `fontspec` together with `xelatex` or `lualatex`